# Add an Expires Header inside a file that is included into another page

Tags: php, caching, header

I have 2 two php pages.One is the main and include the second and i want to add an expires header to it but i get the following error

```
    Warning: Cannot modify header information -
 headers already sent by (output started at..
```

In the first one

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler', 6);

/// lots of html here

include("pageTwo.php");

/// lots of html here

ob_end_flush();
```

In the second page

```
ob_start();
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 3600));

/// lots of html here

ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use mode `6` and try to do it *naked* prior to applying compression.

```
<?php
ob_start();

// include ...

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send headers BEFORE your php page generates any output.

This will **not** work:

```
<?php 
     print 'test';
     header( 'Expires: .... ' );
?>
```

This will work:

```
<?php
     header( 'Expires: .... ' );
     print 'test';
?>
```

So basically you need to change which page sents headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put anything that echos string before the header because the header is suppose to go first and no as a regular text. You can add a regular meta tag. And set the expiry via php
Example

```
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="<?php echo date(whatever type); ?>" />
```